Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: Error returned from API
 try {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .sendPasswordResetEmail(email: emailAddress.text);
                      if (context.mounted) {
                        QuickAlert.show(
                          context: context,
                          type: QuickAlertType.success,
                          title: 'sending..',
                        );
                      }
                    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
                      if (e.code == "user-not-found") {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                            msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
                            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0);
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Forgot Password?",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  ),

This code is for sending a message to reset Password, and I tried to show an error when the user enter a wrong email that doesn't exist, but nothing work and this error kept shoing in the debug consle, I don't know if this error is related with the code that I wrote but when I cli on Forgot password it shows up, please in idea hoe can I fix it.
